FCM API v1: How to attach deeplink for ANDROID push notification
I recently started migration for FCM API from Legacy API to V1.
Documentation suggests a way to attach deeplink in message payload for IOS. But there is no doc which has example for Android.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#java_1
I tried all the payload variables defined in the documentation. Nothing worked.
